# How to store json data in sqlite and read it in flutter/dart?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

```
[
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "some name",
   "hobbies": ["chess", "foot ball"],
   "tv": ["movies", "sports"],
   "category": 1,
   "status": 0
   "other": ["...", "...", "...", "..."]
 },
 .. data is repeated here
]
```

i want to store it a **column** of a **table**
If i have to store it in a fresh table, i need lot of tables and i have to join them.
To keep it simple, i just want to store it in a column as a text.

I tried to minify the json first and stored it in a column of a sqlite table.
I tried to stringify the json then, minified and stored in a column of a sqlite table.

```
String receivedJson = jsonString; //from that table.
var myData1 = json.decode(receivedJson);
print(myData1);
```

In both ways, it is not working.
How do i keep the entire array of json in a single column and retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not a [NoSQL database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) which is what you need for json.

What you want to achieve is possible, I have used [**sembast**](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast) with great success for some projects.

> *Yet another NoSQL persistent store database solution for single process io applications. The whole document based database resides in a single file and is loaded in memory when opened. Changes are appended right away to the file and the file is automatically compacted when needed.*

You install it with:

```
dependencies:
  sembast: ^2.4.10+3
```

And then you can start from this working example:

```dart
// basically same as the io runner but with extra output
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sembast/sembast.dart';
import 'package:sembast/sembast_io.dart';

Future main() async {
  final db = await databaseFactoryIo
      .openDatabase(join('.dart_tool', 'sembast', 'example', 'record_demo.db'));
  var store = intMapStoreFactory.store('my_user');

  var key = await store.add(db, {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "some name",
   "hobbies": ["chess", "foot ball"],
   "tv": ["movies", "sports"],
   "category": 1,
   "status": 0
   "other": ["...", "...", "...", "..."]
 },);
  var record = await store.record(key).getSnapshot(db);
  record =
      (await store.find(db, finder: Finder(filter: Filter.byKey(record.key))))
          .first;
  print(record);
  var records = (await store.find(db,
      finder: Finder(filter: Filter.matches('name', '^John'))));
  print(records);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to this.

NoSQL databases like `Sembast`, `Hive` etc will load all their data into memory on app start.

This may or may not cause you problems later on with high memory usage in the app if you've got thousands of rows.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with storing your json objects as a string in `TEXT` column, and having extra columns for sorting, querying etc, like `id`, `startDateInt` etc.

### Example table definition as per your question:

```
db.execute(
    'CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, json TEXT)',
);
```

### Example insert:

```
await db.rawInsert(
  '''
    INSERT INTO users (json) VALUES (?)
  ''',
  [jsonEncode(obj)],
);
```

### Example retrieve:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = await db.rawQuery(
  'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?',
  [id],
);

YourObjectType? rtnObj;
if (list.isNotEmpty) {
  var jsonMap = json.decode(list[0]['json']) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  rtnObj = YourObjectType.fromJson(jsonMap);
}
```

- Obviously you'll need to put the correct object type, whatever you've got.
- Also you'll need to do your own `fromJson` method.